# How to perform update and save operations in eloquent which are dependent on the last row of a table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, locking

I want to perform an operation similar to the following where the attributes of the object I'm creating depends on the attributes of previous object.

```
$last_row = Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();  
$new_object = new Model()
$new_object.attr1 = $last_row->id + 1
$new_object.attr2 = $last_row->id + 2
$new_object->save()
```

How do you perform the necessary locking in Eloquent to ensure that line 1 is executed by only one transaction at a time?

What other code do I need to add or edit to ensure that two objects do not have the same attr1 and attr2 if line 1 is performed for both objects before either one of the objects is saved.

Comment: return Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

Can you please check using this

Comment: Getting the last row itself isn't the issue though. Let me clear that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this method your are searching for a key that is lower than the key associated on line 1. So even if another object is created before line 2, it will not be considered on your line 2 search.

```
$new_object = Model::create([]);

$last_row = Model::where("id","<",$new_object->id")->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();  

$new_object->attr1 = $last_row->id + 1
$new_object->attr2 = $last_row->id + 2

$new_object->save()
```

You could also use the timestamp to search for the newest created object. If your model have timestamps.

Comment: Is it possible that two objects are created before line 2 is executed?

Comment: Yes, but notice we are searching for a key that is lower than the key associated on line 1. So even if another object is created before line 2, it will not be considered in your line 2 search.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how would you solve this problem if instead of $last_row->id, I was referring to $last_row->attr2 ?

Comment: You could create a delay for the model to be updated. Maybe a while($last_row->attr2 == null and $counter < 50). That would give time for the first model code to run. Also would be wise to throw an exception on error and encapsulate the code inside a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$last_row = Model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();  
$new_object = new Model()
for(i=1 i>3 i++){
$new_object.attr[i] = $last_row->id + [i]
 $new_object->save()}
```